# How to replicate cedar texture in Bondo or wood filler?

Tags: wood-repair

My small garage door has a rough cedar surface. My car slid into it on the outside and put some vertical ruts in the garage door. I'd like to fill the ruts with Bondo or wood filler and then use a small piece of cedar to press into the Bondo or wood filler repairs to give them a cedar-like texture. Am wondering whether to coat the cedar block with oil if some sort so it won't stick to the Bondo or filler so it can make another impression along the rut. What do you suggest to accomplish this?
I have been unable to find answers online.

Comment: there are special rollers you can buy to fabricate wood grain in other materials. Searching for "wood grain roller" gets quite a few results and should get you started. I'm not sure if imprinting with an actual piece of wood works as well as intended. The rollers have quite deep grooves and the elevation difference especially in sanded/planed wood might not be enough to leave an imprint.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. A picture of the condition would help posters make good suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think that trying to push a piece of cedar into the filler will leave you with an *inverse* of the pattern you're looking for and may well stand out almost as much as the gouge itself.

Without a picture, it's hard to say, but I'd imagine that you could hand-sculpt ridges and valleys into the hardening filler to make the patch nearly disappear and that it won't be as difficult as you'd think.

Comment: Yup, negative of the desired pattern! Also agree with the second para 100%. I didn't upvote only cos I don't upvote Answers on Qs destined to be closed because to me this is off-topic.

Comment: I put this in the woodworking stack

Comment: Yes, but the valleys could then become "hills" and vice-versa....

Comment: @DAS I'm afraid I'm not quite following either of your comments. If you'd care to expand on them, I'm sure I (or someone) can respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used a knotted wire wheel (eg. [cheap knotted wheel, not an endorsement](https://www.harborfreight.com/4-1-2-half-inch-stainless-steel-knotted-wire-wheel-91282.html) ) in an angle grinder to good effect. Flatten the bondo first, let dry completely, then progressively (gently)scratch with the wheel.

Comment: Gently and angle grinder, words not often seen together! I know Bondo is tough, but isn't this *super* aggressive?

Comment: With a heavy hand, it can be too aggressive — what you want is to just ‘wipe’ the surface gently (with the grain) in overlapping strokes until you get the look you want.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I'll try my hand at etching with a Dremel tool...